# Joint moment $\tau(XYXYXY)$ in terms of moments of $X$,$Y$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, random-variables, random-matrices

Terry Tao [RMT book](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf) has the following formula for joint moment of freely independent random variables $X,Y$ in Section 2.5

$$\tau(XYXY)=\tau(X)^2\tau(Y^2)+\tau(X^2)\tau(Y)^2-\tau(X)^2\tau(Y)^2$$

Exercise 2.5.17 then asks to prove that this is possible for any joint moment. Is there an easy to describe algorithm for actually constructing such formulas? IE

How would I get $\tau(XYXYXY)$?

Comment: Could you define $\tau(X)$?

Comment: Did you follow Tao's argument for the formula you mention?

Comment: @gtrrebel I followed his examples, but how did he pick to use $Y=\tau(Y)+(Y-\tau(Y))$ substitution for 2.124 on page 208? I'm looking for an explicit procedure I can implement to get formulas for arbitrary joint moments

Comment: @Amir for free probability applied to random matrices, we could have $X$ and $Y$  be $n\times n$ Wigner matrices and $\tau(X)=E[\operatorname{Tr}X]$ as we take $n\to \infty$

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I think the point is that $\tau(Y)$ is a constant while $Y - \tau(Y)$ has mean zero.

Comment: @gtrrebel this concrete example has been shown how to solve in this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/466249/7655) although that doesn't directly help find an implementable algorithm for this task